gsutil URI is not working issue when getting programmatically
When i try to get the gsutil URI programatically "400 Bad request ocuured and say URI is not valid"
I have created a sample dot net core web API code for uploading objects into the Google Cloud bucket and getting the gsutil URI of that object automatically. When I used that automatically given gsutil URI to test the gemini-1.0-pro-vision endpoint, that URI didn't work. But when I manually add objects to the Google bucket and get the gsutil URI manually and after providing it to the gemini-1.0-pro-vision it works. I need to know what is the case for the issue for that automatically generated URI.
